# How to make buttons with a boolean array in Processing?

Tags: java, arrays, button, boolean, processing

I'm following a course in programming in the Java-based environment "Processing". One assignment is to write a program that displays 3 buttons (black). When the button is clicked, that button should change to another colour (grey). We are required to use a boolean[] array. My code is as follows:

```
boolean[] button = new boolean[3];

void setup(){
    size(300,300);
    button[0] = false;
    button[1] = false;
    button[2] = false;
}

void draw(){
    int x = (width/(button.length+1));
    int y = height/2;
    int ellipseSize = 50;
    int radius = ellipseSize/2;
    background(255);
    noStroke();
    fill(0);
    for(int i = 1; i <= button.length; i++){
        ellipse(i*x, y, ellipseSize, ellipseSize);
    }
} 

//shifting array values upon mouse pressing
void mousePressed(){


    int x = (width/(button.length+1));
    int y = height/2;
    int ellipseSize = 50;
    int radius = ellipseSize/2;

    for(int i = 1; i <= button.length; i++){
        button[i] = !button[i];
        if (mouseX > i*x-radius && mouseX < i*x+radius && mouseY > y-radius && mouseY < y+radius){
            if (button[i]){
                fill(150);
            }
        }
        else {
            fill(0);
        }
        ellipse(i*x, y, ellipseSize, ellipseSize);
    } 
}
```

I get an error saying "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3". Can someone help?

Comment: In most programming languages, arrays start at `0`, not `1` like in real life. You've got that correct in your `setup` function, but not in your for loops, which loop from 1 to 3 instead of 0 to 2.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3` because you have tried to access to an illegal index. In Java and in most programming languages arrays start at `0`.
So, in your for loop you need to change `i <= button.length` to `i < button.length`

Answer (score 1):

As few people mentioned arrays in most programming languages start at index `0` and last index is at `button.length - 1` so you need to change `for` loop or `button[i]` call.

But to finish your buttons you will need to understand more about processing. Your draw function is called repeatedly (depending on you fps) and you always clear the sketch with `background` function. Then you set fill color to black and draw three circles. If you change `fill` inside mouse event it might sometimes work (if you click at the same moment as circle is drawn) but it is very bad approach.

You will need to set `fill` according to your `button` array within `draw` function:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= button.length; i++){ //good boundaries for drawing but not for array
    if(button[i-1]) {                    //for array you need correct index
      fill(0);
    }else{
      fill(150);
    }
    ellipse(i*x, y, ellipseSize, ellipseSize);
}
```

And of course change the mouse event to just check if button was clicked and store this information inside `button` array for next drwing.

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= button.length; i++){   //your old boundaries
    if (mouseX > i*x-radius && mouseX < i*x+radius && mouseY > y-radius && mouseY < y+radius){
      button[i-1] = !button[i-1];          //updated index
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
i <= button.length
```

to

```
i < button.length
```

If the length of the array is 3 then button[2] is the last element.